# Image url loading in UITableViewCell Asynchronously But in a order

Tags: ios, image, swift, asynchronous, sdwebimage

I am using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for loading image in a asynchronously to avoid blocking of UI. But Image are not loading in a order way.

[image: This is my Problem]

I want to load image in a ordered way but asynchronously. I don't have exact word to define my problem. If you find any suitable words please edit my question.

Please provide me appropriate solution for it. It would be great if there is any third party library like SDWebImage to catch my requirement. Or it can be done with SDWebImage.

Comment: What order do you mean ? How do you load image, gcd ? So it should load image in sequential order 1,2, 3, ... 100

Comment: Means 1,2,3,4, in this order.

Comment: But image loaded in 1 3 5 8. in an unordered way @GeneratorOfOne

Comment: So, do you  use GCD to load image ?

Comment: I am using this popular SDWebImage. I dont know it using GCD or not

Comment: you can control an order of sending requests, but it doesn't means that you will receive  responses from some server in the same order (if you don't have control over that service).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load your images in order, that is not what asynchronous is about... Asynchronous means, that all images currently visible are loading at the same time. But you don't know which image will be loaded the first, so that's why this happens.

If you would send a request for every image, and then wait for the response before you send a new request, this would take way to much time.

What you can do is, still load them asynchronously, but show them in an ordered way.

I see that you can load images independently too, so one option is to load the images that currently visible, and then show them in an order with the help of a counter.

Comment: can i implement your solution with SDWebImage? or any other library. I want to manage image caching also?

Comment: Yes, i have seen a possible solution with SDWebImage using Independently loading images, here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.7.3/#user-content-using-asynchronous-image-downloader-independently , but I am not sure about image caching

Comment: But I have to fetch the image urls first then download them from webservice then hit agian for other inforamtion while showing the image.